# Coq matrix manipulation

Tags: matrix, coq

I am trying to use marices in Coq. I found la library that does exactly what I need, but being very new in Coq, I can't figure out a way to prove meaningful properties.

The library is [SQIRE](https://github.com/inQWIRE/SQIR), and it defines a matrix as such :

```
Definition Matrix (m n : nat) := nat -> nat -> C.
```

Now, There are some working examples in the project such as:

```
Definition V0 : Vector 2 := 
  fun x y => match x, y with 
          | 0, 0 => C1
          | 1, 0 => C0
          | _, _ => C0
          end.
```

(so `V0` is the column vector (1,0) )

```
Definition I (n : nat) : Matrix n n := 
  (fun x y => if (x =? y) && (x <? n) then C1 else C0).
```

and

```
Lemma Mmult00 : Mmult (adjoint V0) V0 = I 1. Proof. solve_matrix. Qed.
```

So first thing I tried is this :

```
Definition test : Matrix 2 2 :=
  fun x y => match x, y with
          | 0, 0 => 0
          | 0, 1 => 1
          | 1, 0 => 2
          | 1, 1 => 3
          | _, _ => 0
          end.

Definition test2 : Matrix 2 2 :=
  fun x y => match x, y with
          | 0, 0 => 0
          | 0, 1 => 2
          | 1, 0 => 4
          | 1, 1 => 6
          | _, _ => 0
          end.

Lemma double : test2 = 2 .* test. Proof. solve_matrix. Qed.
```

And no luck Here. So I then tried no enumerate the cases :

```
Lemma testouille : test2 = 2 .* test.
Proof.
  autounfold with U_db.
  prep_matrix_equality.
  assert (x = 0 \/ x = 1 \/ x >= 2)%nat as X.
  omega.
  destruct X as [X|X].
  - { (* x = 0 *)
      subst.
      assert (y = 0 \/ y = 1 \/ y >= 2)%nat as Y.
      omega.
      destruct Y as [Y|Y].
      - { (* y = 0 *)
          subst.
          simpl.
          field.
        }
      - {
          destruct Y as [Y|Y].
          - { (* y = 1 *)
              subst.
              simpl.
              field.
            }
          - { (* y >= 2 *)
              subst. (* I can't operate for each y, recursions ?*)
              simpl.
              field.
            }
        }
    }
  - { 
      destruct X as [X|X].
      - { (* x = 1 *)
          subst.
          assert (y = 0 \/ y = 1 \/ y >= 2)%nat as Y.
          omega.
          destruct Y as [Y|Y].
          - { (* y = 0 *)
              subst.
              simpl.
              field.
            }
          - {
              destruct Y as [Y|Y].
              - { (* y = 1 *)
                  subst.
                  simpl.
                  field.
                }
              - { (* y >= 2 *)
                  subst. (* I can't operate for each y, recursions ?*)
                  simpl.
                  field.
                }
            }
        }
      - { (* x >= 2, I can't operate for each x, recursions ?*)
          subst.
          simpl.
          field.
        }
    } 
Qed.
```

But this didn't work either, Coq seems to be unable to guess that if x is greater than 1, then `test x y` is zero. And at this point, I'm a bit short on ideas. Can somebody come to my rescue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `solve_matrix` just doesn't know what `test` and `test2` are to unfold them.

Here are two possible solutions:

```
Lemma double : test2 = 2 .* test. Proof. unfold test, test2. solve_matrix. Qed.

Hint Unfold test test2 : U_db.

Lemma double' : test2 = 2 .* test. Proof. solve_matrix. Qed.
```

For the longer proof, you're going to have to actually destruct `y` twice so Coq can pattern match on it (you can use `omega` to solve the other cases). There's also a tactic called `destruct_m_eq` that will do the work of breaking things down into cases for you. Here's a shorter manual proof of your lemma:

```
Lemma testouille : test2 = 2 .* test.
Proof.
  autounfold with U_db.
  prep_matrix_equality.
  unfold test, test2.
  destruct_m_eq.
  all: lca.
Qed.
```

Relatedly, I recommend the tactics `lia` and `lra` for solving integer and real equalities, and the derived tactic `lca` for complex number equalities. (`field` seemed to fail in a few instance in your proof.)

For a lighter introduction to QWIRE's matrix library (used by SQIR), I recommend [Verified Quantum Computing](https://rand.cs.uchicago.edu/vqc/index.html), though it does make some changes not reflected in the main branch of QWIRE.